# Positioning of popup box (md-dialog) behaving strange (Angular Material)

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, angular-material

I am working on this resource planning tool where you are able to scroll horizontally through time (going 2 months back and 2 months into the future). For this project I am working with Angular (angular material), NodeJs and Mongo.

When the application first starts or you refresh the page then you will always see the current date (highlighted in light blue, see this screenshot -> http://gyazo.com/cc3c6c390805e55eb7954d714cc77394). Now I have noticed the minute I click on one of my buttons that triggers a md dialog. The dialog box will automatically jump to the beginning of my calendar or to the end depending on which button I click (will jump to the end if I click on the settings button)(see screenshot -> http://gyazo.com/c80617e0243914bd61382be402074edd).

My question is, why is this happening. Is it an angular thing and how to fix this issue so that i will always show on the current view and not scroll all the way to the beginning or to the end

Comment: Depends on how you control the starting date on your calendar. Through an Angular variable? Given your current description, cannot guess what is happening.

Comment: Can you create a jsfiddle for this? It'll be easier to debug.